# Perspecsys and Salesforce integration

Tags: integration

The data in one of our salesforce instances is tokenised by [Perspecsys](http://perspecsys.com/perspecsys-cloud-protection-gateway/appprotex-for-salesforce/). We want to now integrate the salesforce instance with external systems via Informatica (or similar ETL) tool. The integration could be both inbound and outbound. 
What are the challenges of doing so if we are storing the data via the AppProtex gateway server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Perspecsys then the integration to Informatica (or any other ETL tool that uses the Salesforce APIs) should be quite straightforward. You simply need to change the endpoint that Informatica uses to communicate with Salesforce – rather than https://login.salesforce.com you will use the URL of the Perspecsys gateway. This assumes that you are using the Perspecsys Integration Server component, and that Informatica has access to that. It also assumes you have a certificate installed on the Perspecsys Integration Server that is trusted by a root certificate authority (If not, then you will likely need to install the public cert from the root authority into the Informatica trusted hosts list). It makes no difference if the data is inbound or outbound, or if you use tokenisation or encryption – there is no more configuration. If you need further help, I’d suggest contacting Perspecsys Support, who are always helpful.